# how to config l2tp ip sec for multiple connection from each ip

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I installed the l2tp ipsec server on Ubuntu 18.4

Now I can connect to the server and enjoy it. :)
But I can only make a connection!
I don't know why?

When using two mobile phones on the same wifi network with the same l2tp connection details, only one of them can be connected!
Why? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using strongSwan. The issue you seem to be facing is that two L2TP/IPsec clients behind the same NAT, can't be distinguished.

See the "Multiple L2TP-IPsec clients behind same NAT" issue on the following page:

- https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/365

As mentioned there, you can use the strongSwan [connmark plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Connmark) to distinguish multiple clients.

Rebuilding strongSwan with the connmark plugin and patching xl2tpd will take a bit of work